# How can multiple vehicle be move from one station to another by setting its path as in Transport Giant?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Image Showing Vehicle movement]

As shown in figure, I want to move vehicle from one station to another following their own path(left or right).
Want's to make road constructable while playing.
And also vehicle's destination should be set while playing.

How can i do it unity engine and c#?

What is the working mechanism behind it?

Please provide sample code if possible

Comment: You probably need to have a representation of your scene on a grid, or matrix, and calculate a pathfinding from A to B

Comment: or use navmesh.

Answer (score 0):

Should the vehicles find their own way to the station? Then you should use a NavMesh.
Here is an example to move an object to different way points.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveVehicleToWayPoints : MonoBehaviour
{

    private UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    public Transform[] wayPoints; // transform of the stations
    private int currentWayPointIndex = 0;


    void Awake()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
        MoveToNextWayPoint();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (navMeshAgent.enabled)
        {
            if (!navMeshAgent.pathPending &&
                navMeshAgent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
            {
                MoveToNextWayPoint();
            }
        }
    }

    void MoveToNextWayPoint()
    {
        if (wayPoints.Length > 0)
        {
            navMeshAgent.destination = wayPoints[currentWayPointIndex].position;

            float dist = Vector3.Distance(navMeshAgent.destination, transform.position);
            if (dist < 1)
            {
                currentWayPointIndex++;
                currentWayPointIndex %= wayPoints.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with NavMesh is you can't change the city, I think he wants a dynamic solution, so if the city changes, vehicles can recalculate the route, anyway if he hasn't tried any code with that, any solution will be a hell for him xD

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but NavMesh used shortest distance, and the object move one after another colliding.
I want them to move side by side, as while moving from one station to another move from left side of road and while returning move from right side.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1XOUkYUDZU This tutorial is quite good and easy to follow. It is about moving cars on a specific road and about the AI of cars. So that they can dodge other moving objects and so on. I used this tutorial a few years ago to create moving cars in a town.